# How to sync Birthday and Hire-date in Office 365 from local AD?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, user-profile-property, synchronization, aad

I am trying to build birthday and anniversary webpart in office 365. The issue is our local ad users are synced but the birthday and hire-date are not synced in office 365.

I was checking the issue and found that we were using Azure AD Connect and that is not supporting these columns. So I have created 2 custom attribute (birthdate & hiredate) in Azure directory. Then using directory extension attribute sync, I am mapping local ad column in azure ad.

Now I am stuck here. I don't know how can I map these custom attribute with Office 365 columns. Can anyone provide any link how can I do these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use directory extensions to extend the schema in Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) with your own attributes from on-premises Active Directory.

Besides, you need to [refresh the schema](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-installation-wizard#refresh-directory-schema) before these new attributes are visible.

Information about [Azure AD Connect sync: Directory extensions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sync-feature-directory-extensions)

Comment: I already completed these steps. I need steps how can I map the extended attribute to sync with office 365 user profile columns.

Comment: I want to sync birthdate column to sps-birthday column and hiredate to sps-hiredate